# How to run git command to specific projects

Tags: android, git, github

I want to run a git command only to specific repositories.
I know '`repo forall`' will help to run a command to all the git projects in that repo. 
But, I want to run on specific projects.

For an example.

```
repo forall -c "git checkout -t remotes/origin/TESTBRANCH"
```

Will run the git command to checkout to TESTBRANCH for all projects.

But I want to checkout only few projects, 
1. kernel
2. frameworks/av
3. hardware/qcom/media.

Tried as below,

```
repo forall -c "git checkout -t remotes/origin/TESTBRANCH" kernel frameworks/av hardware/qcom/media`
```

But, not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: just go the project path /xyz/project follwed by git command example : `git checkout dev_branch`

Comment: -1 not android problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the documentation (`repo help forall`), the project names should go before the `-c` option:

```
repo forall kernel frameworks/av hardware/qcom/media \
  -c "git checkout -t remotes/origin/TESTBRANCH"
```